# While crawling text span tag doesn't have any text

Tags: html

[image]

web page shows this..

[image]

and here's the html tag.

how can I get the number with python code?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to identify where the number is actually stored in the html structure. (It may be splitted individually in many separate elements, maybe the multiple span we see in the screenshot?)

Because with the provided HTML screenshot, we are defenitely missing informations / part of the the structure which actually contains the displayed number.

Once you have identified the precise element which contains the value, you can retreive it easily via a library like **beautifulsoup**.

Example:

```
URL = "https://www.example.com"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="ResultsContainer").text.strip()
```

Comment: there isn't any text inside... only <span class="UJOP"> ::before <em> ::before ::after </em> ::after</span>

Comment: @user1173330 The information is definitely stored somewhere.

- Maybe you're not looking at the right place in the HTML.
- Maybe the content is stored in the CSS and it is displayed with the ::before or ::after selector of the element. [Example](https://codepen.io/jmdeejay/pen/eYGBWBo)

Without having access to the full context, the best thing I can do is guess.